# How to check which field in a table a foreign key references

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

A foreign key is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that uniquely identifies a row of another table or the same table. In simpler words, the foreign key is defined in a second table, but it refers to the primary key in the first table.

I'm using SQL Developer but I can't seem to find which column in my table holds the foreign key to the other table. When I click on the table, a bunch of tabs show up, among which is the Constraints tab. Here, I can see the foreign key, but I don't see which columns are involved in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Constraints tab. When you click one of the foreign key constraint name, columns wihch is used in the foreign key references will be seen in the Columns view at the bottom of Constraints Tab